# A page with editable small posts made by the admin

Tags: php

I just wanted some overview on how i could make a website page for the user where could be seen small posts sections, with only some text and title maybe images, and which the admin would edit and post in the same page through and editor only visible for the admin.
pls if someone could give me a light to start making it.

here's an image explaining it:

[image: here's an image explaining it]

Comment: The easy way to do this is using a CMS like Workpress or Drupal, do you need to do this in pure PHP?

Comment: yes i will use it for a project of mine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic:

- you upload your post to a table of a database.
- get every rows and assign it into a variable.
- parse the assigned variable, print the item consisting: title and content , into your html page.

It is pretty much like this:

```html
<form action="query to upload this info to your table" method="post">
    <input name="title" value="">
    <input type="text" name="content">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<?php 
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$posts = $conn->query("select * from yourTableName") ;

// print every rows from table into html page
foreach ($posts as $item) {
    
    ?>
    <div>
        <h3><?php $item->title?></h3>
        <hr>
        <p><?php $item->content?></p>
    </div>
    <?php

}
$conn->close();
?>
```